# Can I use UML use cases to model settings?

Tags: uml, use-case, settings

Is correct to represent setting options using use cases?

For example the user can:
- enable background updates
- change map color 
- change interval updates

From https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html

> A use case is a kind of behaviored classifier that specifies a
>   [complete] unit of [useful] functionality performed by [one or more]
>   subjects to which the use case applies in collaboration with one or
>   more actors, and which [for complete use cases] yields an observable
>   result that is of some value to those actors [or other stakeholders]
>   of each subject.

I think options I listed are *"useful"* and yield to *"an observable results that is of some value"* . Am I wrong?

How should I represent this kind of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct don't overthink it.

UML is just a tool if it works that way for you and people with who you work to achieve your goal it is ok. Spending time on making 'correct' UML is probably not best use of your time. Spending time to communicate effectively is best use of your time.

Comment: I did as follows: one diagram with the user as an actor which can do 2 actions for example: 1) pay 2) change settings and then another use cases diagram about settings with the same actor and the above listed options.

Comment: I would do it in one diagram, it still going to be readable. If you would have 50 items on the same diagram then I would group it because it would not be readable.

Comment: UML is super detailed in how it is specified because it was originally envisioned as being used in CASE tools to auto-document code or auto-generate code from documentation. Luckily pretty much no one thinks that doing either of those things are a good idea anymore, so UML is just a set of standards around how you can make different types of visualizations. As long as you are vaguely using the right type of elements to represent what they are supposed to represent, you are fine.